# How to commit a UPDATE in raw SQL in python

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("UPDATE public.rsvp SET status=TRUE WHERE rsvp_id=%s", [rsvp_id])
cursor.execute("SELECT status, rsvp_id FROM public.rsvp WHERE rsvp_id=%s", [rsvp_id])
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

When I execute this in my Django project, I get the row returned as I expect to see it, but later when I select query for the same row, it appears as tho the statement was never really run. In my code, the column "status" defaults to NULL. After this is run, I still see NULL in my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what database you're dealing with, which may change the answer somewhat. However, with most database connections you need to finish with `connection.commit()` to really save changes on the database. This includes both update and insert operations. Failing to `commit()` usually results in a rollback of the actions.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's Postgres